# jQuery css Visibility with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, visibility

I have few div's placed underneath each other and I'm using css visibility to fade them in and out. The reason why I use visibility is so that the div's don't move place.

For fade In I'm using:

```
$('.drop1').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
```

and for fade Out I'm using:

```
$('.drop1').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "hidden"}).animate({opacity: 1.0})}, 200);
```

The **FadeIn works**, but the **fadeOut doesn't work**.

Now, you may think that the problem is the last '**,200**'  but I will need to use that as a delay since the fadeout/visibility:hidden is on mouseleave event after 200ms.

So my question is: How can I do the visibility hidden with animation to act as a fadeOut.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`$('.drop1').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 200);`

Comment: This works but if you call it again, the fade zips by. I reckon one needs to clear the animation queue or something?

Answer (score 58):

why make it so hard, instead of animating the css, you could use the default fade functionality

```
$('.drop1').fadeIn(200);
$('.drop1').fadeOut(200);
```

**edit**

if you however want to fade it out without losing the height .
you can use [fadeTo(duration, opacity, [callback]);](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)

```
$('.drop1').fadeTo(200, 0);
```

check this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ufLwy/1/

Comment: come on, justify the downvote, this is a mutch better way to fadeOut than doing it manually with the animate command, if not then i am missing something here and i would like to know what

Comment: fadeIn'ing out makes it's display to none therefore you lose its height where visibility to hidden it's there but not visible. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ufLwy/

Comment: blazemonger's solution also works, but this fadeTo zero solution is much more elegant.

Comment: This will hide an element not make it invisible

Answer (score 8):

I was having similar issues, and here's what I ended up doing.

```
$.fadeToHidden = function ( selector, duration, complete ) {
    $.when(
        $( selector ).fadeTo( duration, 0 )
    ).done( function(){
        $( selector ).css('visibility', 'hidden')
        complete();
    });
}
```

The reason I did this is that

1. `fadeIn()` / `fadeOut()` uses 'display' which F's up an element's height
2. `fadeTo` doesn't affect `visibility`, so while the element is visually hidden with **opacity:0**, users are still able to interact (i.e. click) the invisible element.
3. `animate()` is asynchronous so chaining CSS at the end doesn't guarantee that it will run when the animation is complete. Only by using the Deferred object that animations return (`$.when()` / `$.done()`) will you be guaranteed that the CSS is applied after ***all*** animations are complete.

EDIT
Alternatively, you could apply to `visibility:hidden` to each individual element once their respective animation is complete. This may be slightly quicker for selecting larger groups of elements, since you're only querying the DOM for the group of elements once.

```
$.fadeToHidden = function ( selector, duration, complete ) {
    $.when(
        $( selector ).fadeTo( duration, 0 , function(){ 
            $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        } )
    ).done( complete );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and I solved it this way:

To fade in :

```
$("#id").css({visibility:"visible", opacity: 0.0}).animate({opacity: 1.0},200);
```

To fade out:

```
$("#id").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 200, function(){
    $("#"+txtid).css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

As you can see, I hide the div "#id" once the animation has ended.
I hope it's not too late

Comment: Thanks for good solution @Miguel Higuera Romero. It helped me to add visibility in animate.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I came across a similar situation and this is what I ended up doing

```
$(".drop1").css("visibility", "visible").show().fadeOut(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the answers but nothing worked well. So tried below code which worked for me.

```
$('.drop1').css('visibility', 'visible').animate({
  opacity: 0
}, 200, function() {
  $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.drop1{ opacity: 0.0; }

$('.drop1').fadeTo( "slow" , 1.0);
```