# The .fadeOut() method to use visibility property instead of display property

Tags: jquery, css, fadeout

The .fadeOut()  method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page and same is for fadeIn().

My Question is can they use visibility property so they the element occupy the space in layout of the page and is not just visible?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use jQuery's [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) and then have a callback set the visibility. Example:

```js
$('#fade').on("click", function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden")
    }) // duration, opacity, callback
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="fade">Click to Fade</a>
<div>This won't move</div>
```

Comment: that will not cause element visibility hidden and element still be clickable :(

Comment: Just add a callback that adds the property on fade complete. Answer updated.

Comment: this is what I am doing with fadeOut() See http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/BTGeR/1/ but I need a better solution

Comment: You are asking for a way to fade out and then set visibility hidden. This is as simple as it gets without writing a custom jQuery plugin.

Comment: OK this means this is the simplest way we can have no other way then calling Call Back Function and doing something to overwrite css  ?

Comment: you should also blank the opacity attribute on the callback because on your solution changing the visibility to visible won't make the element to show cause its opacity will still be 0

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add aria-hidden attribute as well? Make the callback: `$('selector').css("visibility", "hidden").attr( 'aria-hidden', true );`

Answer (score 8):

animate with css opacity seems to achieve a similar effect.

```
$('#element').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
```

Run the same with opacity: 1 to fade back in.

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350370/462002).

Comment: This solution is simple and elegant for certain use-cases, but it bears mention that an element with zero opacity still responds to events (click, key-press, etc.) and participates in the tab-order. The caveat with this strategy is that it has accessibility implications. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden

Answer (score 6):

Just Overwrite  the property in the call back

```
$('Element').on("click", function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).css({"display": "block","visibility": "hidden"});  // <-- Style Overwrite 
    }); 
})​
```