# Hiding and showing div with fadeIn and fadeOut not working

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to hide or show a div based on the following code

```js
$("#click").click(function(){
var x = $("#left-column").css('display');
console.log(x);
if(x=='block'){
   $("#left-column").fadeOut();
}else{
   $("#left-column").fadeIn();
}
```

});

The html file is the following:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 

 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" 

    rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left-column" class="col-3">
        </div>
        <div id="test">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="click">

            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filename.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

The css file is the following:

```
#left-column{
position:relative;
height:100vh;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #727bf5, #282828);
/* max-width:300px;
min-width:200px; */
float:left;

}
#test{
  float:left;
}
#wrapper{
 overflow: hidden;

 }
```

but I am having the following error

filename.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a functionat HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery, so use jQuery:

```
$("#click").click(function(){
   var x = $("#left-column").css('display');
   console.log(x);
   if(x=='block'){
      $("#left-column").fadeOut();
   }else{
      $("#left-column").fadeIn();
   }
});
```

Note that you do not need to return the instruction to hide the div, just hide it.

You also want to test the value of x, not that there IS a value in x.

```js
$("#click").click(function(){
   var x = $("#left-column").css('display');
   console.log(x);
   if(x=='block'){
      $("#left-column").fadeOut();
   }else{
      $("#left-column").fadeIn();
   }
});
```

```css
#wrapper{display:flex;}
#wrapper>div {flex:1;}

#left-column{background:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-column" class="col-3">Stuff</div>
    <div id="test">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="click">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Update:

After updating your question with the additional code, I see a few more issues:

1. You are including multiple versions of jQuery.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filename.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Don't do this - they will conflict. Reduce to only one:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filename.js"></script>
```

Also, is the **complete** contents of your javascript file `src="js/filename.js"` posted in the question?  If so, then you need to wrap your js code in a `document.ready` wrapper:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
       var x = $("#left-column").css('display');
       console.log(x);
       if(x=='block'){
          $("#left-column").fadeOut();
       }else{
          $("#left-column").fadeIn();
       }
    });
});
```

The reason that you need that is because it delays jQuery from binding to the DOM elements *until they actually exist in the DOM*.

Without the `document.ready` wrapper, javascript will try to bind the click event to the `#click` button, but that button might not yet exist in the DOM and it won't work. As a rule of thumb, *ALWAYS* begin your js code with the `document.ready` wrapper. Because this is a basic point, we often do not include that bit of information in our answers - even StackSnippet examples do not need the `document.ready` wrapper -- but your real code *does*.

Comment: follogwed the same steps but got the following . filename.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (plans.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.js:5237)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.4.1.js:5044)

Comment: thanks for the answer and the help i did what you said but there error still persists it works only when i replace fadeOut() and fadeIn() with toggle()

Comment: In that case, try using `.toggleClass` (which adds/removes a class from the element), and then create a class that animates the opacity - like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855985/pure-css-animation-visibility-with-delay) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350178/jquery-css-visibility-with-animation) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320673/can-we-animate-visibility). *NOTE that you must animate the opacity (or even visibility) because `display` is all-or-none / on-or-off -- but `opacity` can be animated.*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
document.getElementById("click").onclick= async()=>{
```

You can use

```
$(document).on("click", "#click",function(){
```

if you want the function to work even on elements that will be created on the page on the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fadeToggle function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click").click(function(){
    $("#left-column").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: does-not work the only function thats works is toggle() but I want to used fadeOut() and fadeIn() to animate it the result

Comment: There may be a conflict with the libraries. Both 3.3 slim and 3.4 are called. Here is a js fiddle for [fadetoggle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kdvjmuc/1/) and [animate](https://jsfiddle.net/935syzou/)

Comment: i used one library but there is still a problem